# fscopyobjectasynch : be asked for decision where file is going to be overwritten

Tags: objective-c, macos, macos-carbon

I am developping a small file copy utility and I am using fscopyobjectasynch to copy files. 
When a file already exists in the destination, I would like to ask the user if he want to keep the original file or to overwrite it.

I am trying to find a way to achive this whith fscopyobjectasynch

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/FSCopyObjectAsync), `FSCopyObjectAsync` will overwrite an existing object at the destination if you give it the `kFSFileOperationOverwrite` flag. If you don't, it won't.

You can present an [NSAlert](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/) to determine whether you should pass that flag.

Comment: It's totally buggy. and imagine I want to copy a whole directory, I would like to control per file.

Comment: What's totally buggy? If you want to control overwriting per-file, you'll need to do the recursion yourself, as `FSCopyObject` does not provide that level of control, and either show an alert for each file or, if you want the UX to not suck, roll your own panel that both shows progress and provides a list of the files the user has yet to decide on.

Comment: http://lists.apple.com/archives/filesystem-dev/2010/Sep/msg00012.html for instance

Comment: Ah. So, another good reason (or two or three) to implement the recursion, at the very least, yourself, then.